# Convert VOB/BUP files to .mp4 and store them in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

So as the title says, I have a couple of files in the VOB/BUP format that I need to convert first to .mp4 (I also have .IFO files and I don't know what that is) and then check for a public url to display them (S3 Bucket) But I don't know which one is the correct service.

I have read about [MediaConvert](https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/), but I'm not quite sure this is the right service for my need.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VOB/BUP/IFO files are typically found on a DVD where:

- IFO files are an index and hold information about the disc contents
- BUP files are backup versions of the IFO files
- VOB files hold the video and audio content

AWS Elemental MediaConvert does not support these as an input (1).
To convert these, you can consider leveraging a different tool that is capable, for example FFMPeg.
Here is an example batch script you can reference that does this:
https://gist.github.com/andreasbotsikas/8bad3df5309dd0383f2e2c450b22481c

You can also potentially have this workflow run on AWS by using AWS Lambda to run FFMPeg (2).

References:

1. Supported input codecs and containers : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/reference-codecs-containers-input.html
2. Processing user-generated content using AWS Lambda and FFmpeg : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/